# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject does not deserialize my json

Tags: c#, json.net

I had many classes and one of them os the following

```
public class DeletePatientCommand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I had the following WCF operation:

```
object command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    "{\"DeletePatientCommand\":{\"Id\":5}}",
    typeof(DeletePatientCommand));
```

The object got deserialized, but its `Id` is always `0` instead of `5`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code, because I'm pretty sure `Assembly.GetType` throws an exception, because [you didn't specify the full name of the type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetType_System_String_System_Boolean_).

Comment: Hi Steven,
I do not specify the full name intentionally as I put my class in the default namespace.

Comment: Please include a full stack trace of the exception  and all its inner exceptions.

Comment: There is no exception thrown!

Comment: dynamic command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(DeletePatientCommand));

does not work as well!

Comment: Have you tried posting `{"Id":5}` instead of `{"DeletePatientCommand":{"Id":5}}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203625/discussion-between-anas-tina-and-steven).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mr. [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) comments, I was posting JSON that is not valid. JSON doesn't include the type name. The following works:

```
object command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    "{\"Id\":5}",
    typeof(DeletePatientCommand));
```

The chat contains useful information as well.